# crash while using carousel

Tags: android

I'm using carousel for going to another activity if there's adata to show
but when click on the caruosel crash the app and here's the log cat
:

> 9-06 11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.university.app/com.university.app.arabic.personalHome}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 09-06
>   11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
>   09-06 11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
>   09-06 11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190) 09-06
>   11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297) 09-06
>   11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at
>   com.university.app.LoginActivity$NetCommunication$ServerCommunication$1.handleMessage(LoginActivity.java:797)
>   09-06 11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-06
>   11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-06 11:16:58.831:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(624):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 09-06
>   11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-06
>   11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-06 11:16:58.831:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(624):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   09-06 11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 09-06
>   11:16:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

here's the code :

```
private void performBottomBarButtonFunction() {

        ImageButton infoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.info_button);
        infoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton academicButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.academic_button);
        academicButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AcademicHomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton eTransactionButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.etransaction_button);
        eTransactionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,
                        E_RegistrationHomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton personalButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.personal_button);
        personalButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.sper);

    }
```

Comment: did you read exception? `ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.university.app/com.university.app.arabic.personalHome}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? `

Comment: @Selvin  <activity android:name=".personalHome" >
             <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.university.app.PERSONAL_AR"/> </intent-filter>
         </activity>

Comment: i think it should be `".arabic.personalHome"` since pakage name is `"com.university.app"` or fully qualified name `"com.university.app.arabic.personalHome"`

Comment: aha thanx that was the problem:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the full package name such as :com.uni.app.arabic.personalHOme